# Add document to Firestore sub-collection dynamically - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

new to SwiftUI and Firebase.  I'm trying to add a document to a Firestore sub-collection.  I have the following code in my view model that works great, if I manually add the document ID to the path.

```
func addOrgData(newOrgs: Org) {
    do {
        let _ = try db.collection("Company").document("9gwENeCMefPEJPOLvuXg").collection("Employees").addDocument(from: newOrgs)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to grab that document ID and pass it to that function.  The basic idea would be to get a list of companies, tap on one, be taken to a list of employees, have an option to add an employee to that list of employees for that company.  Any help would be appreciated.  Happy to add any other parts of my code, if needed.

To add more clarity to what I'm trying to do, the idea would be to present the user with a list of companies, user taps on a company (Acme) and is presented with a list of existing employees and there is a button on the nav bar that allows the user to add a new employee to that company.

I updated my code to:

```
let newEmpRef = db.collection("Company").document()
try newEmpRef.collection("Employees").setData(from: newEmployee)
```

This works in that it creates a new user at that level of the DB, but it creates a new company document with no data and a subcollection of that new empty document.  I can't figure out how, if the user is at the list of Acme employees and taps the "Add Employee" button, that it adds the new employee to the already existing Acme > Employees subcollection. DB structure looks like:

```
Company (collection)
  -> Acme (document) 
    -> Employees (Collection)
      -> Marge Simpson (document)
```

How do I get the document ID for Acme and pass it to the VM to ensure when I create Homer Simpson, he ends up in Acme -> Employees?

Org View Model to get list of Organizations:

```
class OrgViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var org = [Org]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchOrgData() {
    db.collection("Organizations").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No Documents")
            return
        }

        self.org = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Org? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Org.self)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Employee view model to add new employee:

```
class EmployeeViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var newEmployees: Employee

init(newEmployees: Employee = Employee(id: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", orgName: "")) {
    self.newEmployees = newEmployees
}

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func addEmployeeData(newEmployees: Employee) {
    do {
        let orgRef = db.collection("Organizations").document()
        try orgRef.collection("Employees").document().setData(from: newEmployees)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func save() {
    addEmployeeData(newEmployees: newEmployees)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `let newEmpRef = db.collection("Company").document()`  you are creating a new document. That's why it adds the user to a new document and sub collection rather than "Acme"

Somewhere in your Company view model, there should be a firebase document with an ID. Pass that ID to your `document` call in the above function:

```swift
db.collection("Company").document("ID FROM VIEW MODEL")
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

This way, your changes will be made to the right document and sub collection (employees).

edit: to have access to the right ID, you need to get it from a firebase document reference.

I would do this by passing it to the `EmployeeViewModel` initializer, and adding a member to the class:

```swift
private var orgId: String

init(newEmployees: Employee = Employee(id: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", orgName: ""), orgId: String) {
    self.newEmployees = newEmployees
    self.orgId = orgId
}
```

then use it:

```swift
func addEmployeeData(newEmployees: Employee) {
    do {
// here:
        let orgRef = db.collection("Organizations").document(self.orgId)
        try orgRef.collection("Employees").document().setData(from: newEmployees)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @atultw, I add a bit more clarity to the original question.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but what I can't figure out is how to get "ID FROM VIEW MODEL".  If the user has navigated to the company Acme and presses the button to add a new employee to Acme, how do I capture that so the view model knows that the user has navigated to Acme?  I know the answer is probably right in front of me, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Comment: @otterpops to answer that we would need to see much more of your code structure. Can you show your view model?

Comment: View models added to original post.  Thanks for helping with this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @otterpops thanks. You need to pass the document from `OrgViewModel` to `EmployeeViewModel`. I am adding an example to the answer

Comment: Thanks, @atultw.  Apparently, this is above my skill level.  I'm just not getting it.  Thanks for the help.